# StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Boolean] while injecting service

Tags: angular

I am trying to do a simple application with a login page using angular . I want a singleton service to hold the login data and I want that service to be used by the app component . I keep receiving the same error when I try to instantiate the service in the constructor.

This is app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './login-page/login-page.component';
import { NavHeaderComponent } from './nav-header/nav-header.component';
import {LoginService} from "./login.service";
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
LoginPageComponent,
NavHeaderComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
FormsModule
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from "./login.service";
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
private title : string = '*******';
private isLoggedIn : Boolean ;
constructor(loginService : LoginService){
this.isLoggedIn = loginService.CheckLoginStatus();
}
}
```

Here is the service **login.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
private username = "***";
private password = "***";
private isLogin : Boolean = false;
// Variable to check whether the user has logged in or not
constructor(isLogin:Boolean) {
this.isLogin = isLogin;
}
/* Function to check login status */
CheckLoginStatus()   {
return this.isLogin;
}
/* Function to call after the user is logged in */
HasLoggedIn()   {
this.isLogin = true;
}
/* Function to call after the user is logged out */
HasLoggedOut()   {
this.isLogin = false;
}
/*Function to validate User */
validateLogin(username : string , password : string)
{
if(username===this.username && password===this.password)
this.HasLoggedIn();
return this.isLogin;
}
}
```

=
What went wrong here ?

Comment: You need to stop using `Boolean` & instead use `boolean`.

Comment: Thank you  for pointing out the mistake . Even after changing that I see the same error.

Comment: It is working now ! Thanks !